# Why is gdb backtrace output so ugly?

Tags: gdb

Some complex C++ program has many lambda calls. When I invoke `bt` at gdb prompt, it gives me this:
[image]

I have to say it's too ugly to understand. How hard to make that readable and hierarchical for gdb community, so that I can easily know who calls who ?
Do lambda expressions make it hard to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not really a reason things are ugly per se.  Instead what is happening is that gdb simply prints the name of the symbol that it knows, and sometimes C++ symbol names are just unreadably long.

Maybe gdb could be modified to do something about this, but again, there isn't really a reason (which IIUC is what you're asking about) -- just that nobody has tried.

It's also possible to write a Python frame filter for gdb that will shorten symbol names as you like.  This may be best because in general it seems difficult to figure out how to shorten names.